# Moving Block on product page Magento 2.2.7

Tags: layout, product-page, magento2.2.7

I fairly new to this but

I am trying to move a brand logo on my product page from below the product title to below the gallery image.

Normally I would be able to achieve this using my themes

**catalog_product_view.xml**

and adding

`<move element="element.name" destination="product.info.media.image" after="-"/>`

However, I think, (I may be wrong) the extension i am using positions the logo from within **.php** file located within the extensions

**Plugin/Catalog/Block/Product/View/BlockHtmlTitlePluginAbstract.php**

```
    /**
 * Add Brand Label to Product Page
 *
 * @param \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $original
 * @param $html
 * @return string
 */
public function afterToHtml(
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $original,
    $html
) {
    $logoHtml = $this->generateLogoHtml();

    $html = str_replace('/h1>', '/h1>' . $logoHtml, $html);

    return $html;
}
```

If I'm correct and the brand logo is positioned from the .php file does anyone know how i would be able to reposition it below the gallery image?